# Getting the correct IDs of the maximum values for each group of rows

Tags: mysql, max

From a simple table with three rows (id, status, value), I would like to retrieve the id and the value from the row with the maximum value, for each status group.

The simple query I tried is:

```
SELECT t1.status, t1.id, MAX(t1.value) FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.status;
```

The problem is that I do get maximum value for each group, but not the correct id. I get the the id of the first row from each status group...
Is there a simple way to get the proper id?

There are many questions about getting the maximum value, but aren't many about the id. Couldn't find an answer for that one..

Comment: Use an 'ORDER BY desc' on t1.value, and then take the first row (in addition to your GROUP BY)

Comment: Sounded like a promising solution. I tried it with a subquery instead of sthe simple t1, but it still gives me the same answer. would you preform the ORDER by in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by t1.status and t1.id use below query-

```
SELECT t1.status, t1.id, MAX(t1.value) FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.status,t1.id;
```

Comment: could you explain the logic? it doesn't work.

Comment: Since you are selecting id so you should group by id else id will come wrong for the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a subquery to get the id that has the max value:

```
   SELECT a.status, (select b.id
                       FROM t1 as b
                       where b.status=a.status
                       group by b.status
                       HAVING b.value=max(b.value)), 
           MAX(a.value) 
    FROM t1 as a
    GROUP BY a.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea than what I put in the comment. Not the most efficient but should get the job done:

```
WITH maxes(max) as (
    SELECT MAX(t1.value), t1.status
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY t1.status),
SELECT t1.status, t1.id, t1.value
   FROM t1, maxes
   WHERE t1.value = maxes.max AND t1.status = maxes.status;
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is m.max?

Comment: Ah should be `maxes.max`. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
SELECT v.status, v.id, v.value
 FROM 
(SELECT statues, MAX(value) AS maxVal
FROM t1
GROUP BY status) as m
INNER JOIN t1 v
ON v.status = m.status 
AND v.value = m.maxVal;
```

Thank you!